# How to post XML data with cURL using cmd in windows 7?

Tags: xml, curl, cmd

I am trying to post some xml data using curl on command line. Particularly I m trying to run the following command to connect to a billing service provider:

```
curl https://core.spreedly.com/v1/gateways.xml \
    -u 'secretKey' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' \
    -d '<gateway><gateway_type>test</gateway_type></gateway>'
```

However I m keep getting the following error:

```
< was unexpected at this time.
```

How should I type my xml data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Redirection symbols can be escaped by placing those within double quotes `"`.

Instead of saying

```
'<gateway><gateway_type>test</gateway_type></gateway>'
```

you need to say

```
"<gateway><gateway_type>test</gateway_type></gateway>"
```